# Using JQuery variable outside local scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, asynchronous, scope

I am struggling with an issue that I can't define. I've pieced together this JQuery for uploading an image. When generating the preview, I'm using FileReader to get the image dimensions in order to control the resizing of the preview. As far as I can tell, that is working fine when I do `console.log ($preview);` inside `img.onload = function() {};`. But If I do that outside the function, it is undefined. I need access to the variable in the following functions. I've been studying scope, and from what I understand if I don't declare the variable inside the function like `var variable = x;` it shouldn't be local. I've also searched and searched the internet and SO for a solution but nothing seems to fit.

Is this an asynchronous issue or is it an issue with scope even though `$preview` is defined initially outside these functions? Can I return it from inside the function like in PHP?

```
var $preview;
if (previewsOn) {
    if (isImgFile(ui.file)) {

    var reader = new FileReader;

    reader.onload = function() {
        var img = new Image;

        img.onload = function() {

            if (img.width > 120 || img.height > 100) {

                var maxWidth = 120;
                var maxHeight = 100;
                var ratio = 0;
                var width = img.width;
                var height = img.height;

                if (width > maxWidth){
                   ratio = maxWidth / width;
                   $preview = $('<img/>').css("width", maxWidth);
                   $preview = $('<img/>').css("height", height * ratio);
                   height = height * ratio;
                   width = width * ratio;
                }

                if (height > maxHeight){
                   ratio = maxHeight / height;
                   $preview = $('<img/>').css("height", maxHeight);
                   $preview = $('<img/>').css("width", width * ratio);
                   width = width * ratio;
                   height = height * ratio;
                }
            } else {
                $preview = $('<img/>');
            }
        };

        img.src = reader.result;
     };

     reader.readAsDataURL(ui.file);

     ui.readAs('DataURL', function(e) {
        $preview.attr('src', e.target.result);
     });

        } else {

           $preview = $('<i/>');
           ui.readAs('Text', function(e) {
                $preview.text(e.target.result.substr(0, 15) + '...');
           });
        }

    } else {
       $preview = $('<i>no preview</i>');
    }

$($previewImg).empty(); $($preview).appendTo($previewImg);
    $('<td/>').text(Math.round(ui.file.size / 1024) + ' KB').appendTo($row);
        $('<td/>').append($pbWrapper).appendTo($row);
        $('<td/>').append($cancelBtn).appendTo($row);
        return $progressBar;
    };
```

Comment: It is an asynchronous issue.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to resolve it?

Comment: Use `$.Deferred()` or use callback function, or use variable only after its initialization. But most important: use proper code indent style. Right now it is weird and confusing.

Comment: I did my best to indent it, but it's difficult on SO. It was indented properly before pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign value to $preview in .onload handler, but it is called some time later. According to your code following change could help:

```
var $preview;
if (previewsOn) {
    if (isImgFile(ui.file)) {
        $preview = $("<img/>");
```

(added initialization code after if statement)

Then replace lines like

```
$preview = $('<img/>').css("width", maxWidth);
```

with

```
$preview.css("width", maxWidth);
```

And remove

```
} else {
    $preview = $('<img/>');
```

So variable will not be re-assigned.

**answer to comment**

Failure scenario timeline:

1. you code registers onload handler
2. you code continues execution, trying to do smth with $preview, which has no value yet
3. image finally loaded and onload handler triggered, assigning value to $preview

Comment: Hmmm. Well it seems to have worked, but I am hoping to understand why. Was the issue that `$preview` needed the default of `$("<img/>")`? Then that element is just modified by the other functions?

Comment: see answer above, i've added failure scenario